# How do I extract hashtags from tweets in R?

Tags: regex, r, tweets

I know this question had been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952835/retrieve-all-hashtags-from-a-tweet) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855535/regular-expression-to-extract-words-names-hashtags-and-phrases-from-tweets) but there was a small problem when I tried it out:

```
x<- str_extract("Hello peopllz! My new home is #crazy gr8! #wow", "#\S+")
Error: '\S' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "#\S"
```

I changed the regex to `"#(.+) ?"`, `"#\\s"`, but they did not extract the hashtags.

I then tried the gsub way:

```
x<- gsub("[^#(.+) ?]","","Hello! #London is gr8. #Wow")
```

It gave: `" #  . #"`

Any ideas where I am going wrong? I'd like my output as a vector/list of all the hashtags in the tweet(without the hashes!)

Edit: I would prefer not tokenizing the tweet, because:
1. I am not tokenizing the tweets for the rest of my program,
2. It would become a very expensive step were I to scale it to handle large volumes of tweets.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `"#\\S+"` instead of `"#\S+"`.

```
str_extract_all("Hello peopllz! My new home is #crazy gr8! #wow", "#\\S+")
# [[1]]
# [1] "#crazy" "#wow"
```

There are two levels of parsing going on here. Before the low level regexp function within `str_extract` gets the pattern you want to search for (*i.e.* `"#\S+"`) it is first parsed by R. R does not recognize `\S` as a valid escape character and throws an error. By escaping the slash with `\\` you tell R to pass the `\` and `S` as *two normal characters* to the regexp function, instead of interpreting it as *one escape character*.

#### Side track

This can produce rather bizarre expressions. Imagine that you have a list of addresses to computers on a windows network on the form of `"\\computer"`. To search for it you would need to type `str_extract(adr, "\\\\\\w+")` which would turn into `"\\\w+"` internally and then search for.

Comment: That works, thanks! But how do I extract all hashtags from a tweet? This would give me the first occurring hashtag. Any way of going around it?

Comment: x<- gregexpr("#(\\S+)","Hello! #London is gr8. #Wow")   gives the position & lengths of the tweets which can be utilized to extract the hashtags, but no simpler way of doing it?

Comment: Great answer, might want to use ``#\\w+`` instead of ``#\\S+`` so punctuation isn't included

Answer (score 3):

Just chiming in. Depending on how you access the twitter data, this information may already be parsed for you.  For example, if you access the sample stream, the raw JSON format has an entry that parses the references, tags, etc., as an array for you.  See [twitter api documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/show/%3aid) here.

Answer (score 0):

how about replace `#\S+` with `#\\\S+`